# How are distributed election algorithms implemented in practice (Bully, Ring algorithm)?

Tags: networking, network-programming, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

I am learning about these algorithms in class and in textbooks. However, these algorithms assume that the network topology does not change and that the network is reliable. We know this is not true for a network in real life. For example, if each node can only communicate with a subset of the nodes (and the relationship is not bidirectional), many weird cases emerge.

My question is how are these algorithms actually implemented in production distributed systems, in face of these challenges. I seems like we would need immensely complicated solutions than what these simple algorithms provide.

What is the point of learning these algorithms if they don't even work in real software.

Comment: You can look at the OSPF DR/BDR elections for your Bully algorithm, and something like spanning tree for your ring algorithm (although, it is designed to turn a ring into a tree because a ring leads to bad things). There are many real-world examples of those in networking. "_these algorithms assume that the network topology does not change and that the network is reliable._" That is simply false, and new elections take place on failures or other changes.